# Get and set (private) property in PHP as in C# without using getter setter magic method overloading

Tags: php, properties, getter-setter, setter, getter

### Summary

Code sample:

```
Class People {
    // private property.
    private $name;

    // other methods not shown for simplicity.
}
```

Straight forward. Let me assume that `$name` is a **PRIVATE** class member *(or property, variable, field, call it as you wish)*. Is there any way to do these in PHP:

```
$someone = new People();
$someone->name = $value;
$somevar = $someone->name;
```

**WITHOUT** using `__get($name)` and `__set($name, $value)`.

---

### Background

I needed to check the assigned `$value`, therefore I simply need a getter setter like this:

```
getName();
setName($value);
```

And **NOT** necessarily a getter setter magic method overloading like this:

```
__get($value); 
__set($value, $name);
```

That said, I simply need a getter setter. But that's **NOT** what I want. It just doesn't feel like object oriented, for people from static typed language such as C++ or C# might feel the same way as I do.

*Is there any way to get and set a private property in PHP as in C# without using getter setter magic method overloading?*

---

***Update***

### Why Not Magic Method?

1. There are rumors floating around the web that magic method is 10x slower then explicit getter setter method, I haven't tested it yet, but it's a good thing to keep in mind. *(Figured out that it's not that slow, just 2x slower, see the benchmark result below)*
2. I have to stuff everything in one huge method if I use magic method rather then split them into different function for each property as in explicit getter setter. *(This requirement might have been answered by [ircmaxell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4925317/get-and-set-private-property-in-php-as-in-c-without-using-getter-setter-magic/4925483#4925483))*

### Performance Overhead Benchmarking

I'm curious about performance overhead between using magic method and explicit getter setter, therefore I created my own benchmark for both method and hopefully it can be useful to anyone read this.

**With magic method and method_exist:**

*(click [here](http://codepad.org/UZtfPQom) to see the code)*

- Getter costs 0.0004730224609375 second.
- Setter costs 0.00014305114746094 second.

**With explicit getter setter:**

*(click [here](http://codepad.org/5Cro4yEv) to see the code)*

- Getter costs 0.00020718574523926 second.
- Setter costs 7.9870223999023E-5 second (that's 0.00007xxx).

That said, both setter and getter with magic method and method exists justs costs 2x than the explicit getter setter. I think it's still acceptable to use it for a small and medium scale system.

Comment: Not doable with your requirements. __get and __set are the necessary language construct for implementing C#-esque smart fields.

Comment: I guess that's what I'll be hearing from everyone, just curious if there's a real "magic" method that doesn't use magic method. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nope.

However what's wrong with using `__get` and `__set` that act as dynamic proxies to `getName()` and `setName($val)` respectively?  Something like:

```
public function __get($name) { 
    if (method_exists($this, 'get'.$name)) { 
        $method = 'get' . $name; 
        return $this->$method(); 
    } else { 
        throw new OutOfBoundsException('Member is not gettable');
    }
}
```

That way you're not stuffing everything into one monster method, but you still can use `$foo->bar = 'baz';` syntax with private/protected member variables...

Comment: "Method is not **gettable**" perhaps? ;-)

Comment: Nice thought. I didn't even think of proxying explicit getter setter from magic method. Figured out that using magic method only costs 2x then the explicit getter setter, unlike the rumors that said 10x slower, who's spreading that rumor?

Comment: @Hendra: It's a micro-optimization at best to worry about that since it's quite fast even if it was 10x slower.  And it was likely slower in older versions of PHP, but recent ones are much faster...

Answer (score 3):

```
ReflectionClass is your salvation
```

I know it's too late for Hendra but i'm sure it will be helpfull for many others.

In PHP core we have a class named ReflectionClass wich can manipulate everything in an object scope including visibility of properties and methods.

It is in my opinion one of the best classes ever in PHP.

Let me show an example:

If you have an object with a private property and u want to modify it from outside

```
$reflection = new ReflectionClass($objectOfYourClass);
$prop = $reflection->getProperty("PrivatePropertyName");
$prop->setAccessible(true);
$prop->setValue($objectOfYourClass, "SOME VALUE");
$varFoo = $prop->getValue();
```

This same thing you can do with methods eighter;

I hope i could help;

Comment: `$prop->setValue($objectOfYourClass, "SOME VALUE");`

Comment: *"If you have an object with a private property and u want to modify it from outside"* - in other words, if you want to **violate the contract** that the object implementer created. While `ReflectionClass` is certainly useful, considering it for a use like this is ... questionable.

Comment: "considering it for a use like this" - A use like this is **exactly** what it is **meant** to do, and also, -- Get and set (private) property in PHP as in C# without using getter setter magic method overloading -- this is exactly what the question is asking for

Answer (score 2):

If using magical properties doesn't seem right then, as already pointed out by other posters, you can also consider [ReflectionClass::getProperty](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getproperty.php) and [ReflectionProperty::setAccessible](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php).

Or implement the necessary getter and setter methods on the class itself.

In response to the language features issue that you raised, I'd say that having a dynamically typed language differ from a statically typed one is expected. Every programming language that has OOP implements it somewhat differently: **[Object-Oriented Languages: A Comparison](http://archive.eiffel.com/doc/manuals/technology/oo_comparison/)**.

Comment: Thank, I'm just curious if there are techniques or methods that I haven't know. By the way, what was that link you posted, there's no php in it, isn't it for eiffel?

Comment: @Hendra Uzia: It was meant as an illustration that there is no canonical OOP standard. Features depend on a specific language and applying the OOP rules of C++ to PHP isn't necessarily a good thing to do. Rules are based on certain assumptions and in a different language these tend to become invalid.

Comment: I see, It's just that C has been influencing a lot of language, and people will always compare language based on what they are familiar with just like me.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira Thanks for pointing it out. Should be fine now.

Answer (score 0):

```
class conf_server
{

private $m_servidor="localhost";
private $m_usuario = "luis";
private $m_contrasena = "luis";
private $m_basededatos = "database";

public function getServer(){
    return $this->m_servidor;
}
public function setServer($server){
    $this->m_servidor=$server;
}
public function getUsuario(){
    return $this->m_usuario;
}
public function setUsuario($user){
    $this->m_usuario=$user;
}
public function getContrasena(){
    return $this->m_contrasena;
}
public function setContrasena($password){
    $this->m_contrasena=$password;
}
public function getBaseDatos(){
    return $this->m_basededatos;
}
public function setBaseDatos($database){
    $this->m_basededatos->$database;
}
}
```

Comment: What is your point? Yes, you can write functions like that. In any language. PHP is no exception. What about those functions are you commenting on?  [OP already said  *"But that's NOT what I want."*. He was hoping for a "property" syntax.]